# element location in CSS animation with different screen displays

Tags: html, css, css-animations

**Project**

adding circles that expands when users hover, on an image so it adds interesting animation to it.

**Problem**

After I was done I realized that depending on the screen display used, the elements (red balls) I put over the image are in different locations. How can I do this so it works on all devices except mobile.

You will get a better idea of what im doing when you see the demo

**HTML**

```
<div><img class="tree" title="source: imgur.com" src="http://i.imgur.com/1dDCOyq.png" alt="" />
<div class="circle-top-left">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">
<p class="para">This is where sentence goes</p>
consulting 1

</div>
</div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="circle-top-right">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">
<p class="para">This is where sentence goes</p>
consulting 3

</div>
</div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="circle-bot-right">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">
<p class="para">This is where sentence goes</p>
consulting

</div>
</div>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div class="circle-bot-left">
<div class="circle__wrapper">
<div class="circle__content">
<p class="para">This is where sentence goes</p>
consulting 4

</div>
</div>
</div>
&nbsp;

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footer_top_holder {
    border-top: #17171A solid 8px;
    box-shadow: none;
}



/* Home page tree image CSS */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tree {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.circle-top-left {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: #b20312;
    top: 103.5px;
    left: 26.3%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle-top-left:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2.5em;
    color: transparent;
    left: 160px;
    top: 45px;
}

.circle-top-right {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: #b20312;
    top: 49.5px;
    left: 52.5%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle-top-right:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2.5em;
    color: transparent;
    left: 49%;
    top: 35px;
}

.circle-bot-right {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: #b20312;
    top: 267.5px;
    left: 75%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle-bot-right:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2.5em;
    color: transparent;
    left: 74%;
    top: 215px;
}

.circle-bot-left {
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 9px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    background: #b20312;
    top: 379px;
    left: 19.6%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.circle-bot-left:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 2.5em;
    color: transparent;
    left: 8%;
    top: 320px;
}

.circle__wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title_subtitle_holder {
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.circle__content {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.para {
    line-height: 25px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle-top-right:hover .para,
.circle-bot-right:hover .para,
.circle-top-left:hover .para,
.circle-bot-left:hover .para  {
    display: block;
}

.circle-top-right:hover span,
.circle-bot-right:hover span,
.circle-top-left:hover span,
.circle-bot-left:hover span {
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/rtr365/pen/KddNrV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your element circles to start out on top of the image's circles by replacing your hard-coded `left` styles with the following:

```
.circle-top-left {
  left: calc(50% - 260px);
}

.circle-top-right {
  left: calc(50% + 29px);
}

.circle-bot-right {
  left: calc(50% + 275px);
}

.circle-bot-left {
  left: calc(50% - 335px);
}
```

[**CodePen 1**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYYgpz)

If you want the circles to always expand in place, replace your hard-coded `left` and `top` hover styles with the following:

```
.circle-top-left:hover, .circle-top-right:hover,
.circle-bot-right:hover, .circle-bot-left:hover {
  transform: translate(-90px, -90px);
}
```

[**CodePen 2**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGGOdJ)